# copy some directories randomly to another directory in python

Tags: python, operating-system, bioinformatics, fasta, shutil

```
import shutil
import os
import random
source = os.listdir("/1/scratch/bacteria")
destination = "/1/scratch/library/Bacteria/"
for dir in source:
         result = []
         for i in range(100):
                 index = random.randrange(0, len(source))
         result.append(dir[index])
         shutil.copy(result, destination)
```

I have 5000 directories each include one fasta file, I want to randomly select 100 of these directories  and copy to another directory.
I could have concatenate them all into multi-fasta file and then make a sub-set from them but the program I'm working with likes to have separate directory for each fasta file.

> indexError: string index out of range

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow. What's your question? What problem did you run into?

Comment: wouldn't you want your for statement to be `for i in range(len(source)):`?

Comment: Thanks. I want to copy 100 directories from total 5000 directories into another directory randomly.

Answer (score 0):

The `IndexError` is caused by this block of code:

```
for i in range(100):
    index = random.randrange(0, len(source))
result.append(dir[index])
```

At the end of the `for`, `index` will have a random value between `0` and `len(source)-1`, and then you are using it to index a char within the `dir` string. There are no guarantees that `dir` (which is the name of a folder within your source dir) will be longer (in number of chars) than the number returned by the `randrange`.

Don't reinvent the wheel, take a look at [random.sample](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample), it will pick `k` unique elements from your `source` list.